# Sinatra/Ruby Scope Issue

Tags: ruby, scope, sinatra

I was wondering, why is `H` in global scope in https://github.com/antirez/lamernews/blob/master/app.rb? You can see it defined on line 53, used on line 77, and out on line 127 in https://github.com/antirez/lamernews/blob/master/page.rb.

Any sage advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because constants, named with a leading capital letter, are accessible anywhere in the class or module in which they're defined, and outside using the leading `::`.

Comment: Is it treated like a class variable? In this code, an object has been assigned to it, which is dynamic. Why would a constant rather than a class variable be used?

Comment: @Cenoc I'm not sure; it's likely not the way I'd have implemented it. I mean, you're always assigning an object to a constant, and you can always mutate the state of a constant (and get a warning if you try to mutate the reference itself).